# how to add children to existing array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array in javascript:

```
var elements = [ // original hierarhical array to display
            {key:10, label:"Web Testing Dep.", open: true, children: [
                {key:20, label:"Elizabeth Taylor"},
                {key:30, label:"Managers",  children: [
                    {key:40, label:"John Williams"},
                    {key:50, label:"David Miller"}
                ]},
                {key:60, label:"Linda Brown"},
                {key:70, label:"George Lucas"}
            ]},
            {key:110, label:"Human Relations Dep.", open:true, children: [
                {key:80, label:"Kate Moss"},
                {key:90, label:"Dian Fossey"}
            ]}
        ];
```

If I want to add a whole new element I can use a `push()`. But I want to add a part of an element.
for exemple I want to add

```
var toAdd = {key:100, label:"Johny Dep"}
```

To the children of key 10 "web testing dep.". 
Is it also possible with a `push()`?

Comment: You can use push on any array. It does not matter if that array is itself part of a larger data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for getting the not to insert the new object.

```js
function addToStructure(structure, object, parent) {
    structure.some(function iter(a) {
        if (a.key === parent) {
            a.children = a.children || [];
            a.children.push(object);
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(iter);
    });
}

var elements = [{ key: 10, label: "Web Testing Dep.", open: true, children: [{ key: 20, label: "Elizabeth Taylor" }, { key: 30, label: "Managers", children: [{ key: 40, label: "John Williams" }, { key: 50, label: "David Miller" }] }, { key: 60, label: "Linda Brown" }, { key: 70, label: "George Lucas" }] }, { key: 110, label: "Human Relations Dep.", open: true, children: [{ key: 80, label: "Kate Moss" }, { key: 90, label: "Dian Fossey" }] }];

addToStructure(elements, { key: 100, label: "Johny Dep" }, 10);

console.log(elements);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `elements[0].children.push(toAdd)`

```js
var elements = [ // original hierarhical array to display
            {key:10, label:"Web Testing Dep.", open: true, children: [
                {key:20, label:"Elizabeth Taylor"},
                {key:30, label:"Managers",  children: [
                    {key:40, label:"John Williams"},
                    {key:50, label:"David Miller"}
                ]},
                {key:60, label:"Linda Brown"},
                {key:70, label:"George Lucas"}
            ]},
            {key:110, label:"Human Relations Dep.", open:true, children: [
                {key:80, label:"Kate Moss"},
                {key:90, label:"Dian Fossey"}
            ]}
        ];
var toAdd = {key:100, label:"Johny Dep"}
elements[0].children.push(toAdd)
console.log(elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
elements.filter(function(e) {
    return e.key === 10;
})[0].children.push(toAdd);
```

Where `toAdd` is `{ key: 100, label: "Johny Depp" }`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to **find** the element that you want to modify:

```
var element_to_modify = elements.find(function(element) {
  return element.key == 10;
});
```

Then, modify the item by pushing into their children the new object:

```
element_to_modify.children.push(toAdd)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) suggest in his comment that we can push an element or object in an array. It does not matter if that array is itself part of a larger data structure.

**DEMO**

```js
var elements = [ // original hierarhical array to display
            {key:10, label:"Web Testing Dep.", open: true, children: [
                {key:20, label:"Elizabeth Taylor"},
                {key:30, label:"Managers",  children: [
                    {key:40, label:"John Williams"},
                    {key:50, label:"David Miller"}
                ]},
                {key:60, label:"Linda Brown"},
                {key:70, label:"George Lucas"}
            ]},
            {key:110, label:"Human Relations Dep.", open:true, children: [
                {key:80, label:"Kate Moss"},
                {key:90, label:"Dian Fossey"}
            ]}
        ];
        
var toAdd = {key:100, label:"Johny Dep"}

elements[0].children.push(toAdd);

console.log(elements);
```